# How to handle models with a large amount of range fields

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord

I have a Rails app working with large models that hold many ranges. For example foo_min, foo_max, bar_min, bar_max, etc.

Right now I'm storing each of these on the model itself which is okay I guess. But I am concerned that my model will get too large if there is, let's say, 10 ranges (= 20 fields.. yikes).

What I was thinking is making a generic Range model that stores min/max. Then my model can have

```
class Example
  belongs_to :foo, class_name: 'Range'
  belongs_to :bar, class_name: 'Bar'
end
```

My concern with this is that I will be storing a bunch of otherwise unrelated models in the Range table. Foo/Bar may be completely unrelated, they only make sense in the context of an `Example` yet they are stored in the same table.

Is this approach better than just storing the potentially many _min and _max fields? Is there an even better way?

Comment: Do you need to run queries on the range? Eg: give me rows within the range?

Comment: I think if you move ranges to separate model it will be a hassle with relationships instead. It would be a more normalized DB I guess, but then handling multiple columns should be faster with Rails than multiple associations.

Comment: Are you always using all the ranges? You aren't really gaining anything by splitting it up if you always use them.

Comment: I don't know to be honest. I want a flexible solution, I think judging by the nature of the project that sorting/searching by range (both minimum and maximum) might be necessary.